# Send an email using Gmail API in Typescript/Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, email, ionic-framework, gmail

I want to send an email on my application using my gmail account. I am using Ionic and followed https://www.sitepoint.com/sending-emails-gmail-javascript-api/ and https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send to send emails.
This is what I have for initializing client

```
client_id: gapiKeys.client_id,
discoveryDocs: ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/gmail/v1/rest"],
scope: [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly",
    "https://mail.google.com/",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send"
].join(" ")
```

When I only put "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly" under scope, I can get the list of labels of the user, but I get error 401 when I use mail.google.com, modify, compose, and send. Below is my code for sending an email.

```
sendEmail() {
let top = {
  'To': 'someRecipient@gmail.com',
  'Subject': 'Test'
}

var email = '';
for(var header in top) {
  email += header += ": "+ top[header] + "\r\n";
}
email += "\r\n" + "this is a testing email message.";

var request = (gapi.client as any).gmail.users.messages.send({
  'userId': 'me',
  'resource': {
    'raw': window.btoa(email).replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_')
  }
});
request.execute();
}
```

With this code, I get

```
POST https://content.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send?alt=json&key=someKey--M 401 ()
```

The address in the error shows the following:

```
{
 "error": {
 "errors": [
 {
  "domain": "global",
  "reason": "required",
  "message": "Login Required",
  "locationType": "header",
  "location": "Authorization"
 }
],
"code": 401,
"message": "Login Required"
}
}
```

What should I do to send an email on application using Ionic (not email composer provided by Ionic)? I don't have to use Gmail API.

Answer (score 0):

Your authorization to access the server is not existent.
Use basic trouble shooting to determine the problem.
Here is a link that tells you what is happening. 
You will have to provide some sort of authentication in the header no matter how you send the email.

https://httpstatuses.com/401